# Solidity, Foundry - testing stdstore

Tags: solidity, foundry-forge

I'm following https://github.com/Thaddeus19/NFTContracts_with_Foundry/blob/main/src/test/NFTTest.t.sol.
Here's my test contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.4;

import {Vm} from "@std/Vm.sol";
import "@std/Test.sol";
import "../src/ETHNFTBridgeContract.sol";
import "./mocks/MockERC721.sol";

contract ETHNFTBridgeContractTest is Test {
    ETHNFTBridgeContract public bridgeContract;
    MockERC721 public mockERC721;

    function setUp() public {
        bridgeContract = new ETHNFTBridgeContract();
        mockERC721 = new MockERC721();
    }

    function testContractName() public {
        string memory name = mockERC721.name();
        assertEq(name, "TestNFT");
    }

    function testMintAndSuppply() public {
        address alice = address(3);
        hoax(alice, 2 ether);

        mockERC721.mint(alice);
        mockERC721.mint(alice);

        assertEq(mockERC721.tokenId(), 2);
    }

    function testAliceIsOwner() public {
        address alice = address(3);
        hoax(alice, 2 ether);
        mockERC721.mint(alice);
        uint256 slotOfNewOwner = stdstore
            .target(address(mockERC721))
            .sig(mockERC721.ownerOf.selector)
            .with_key(1)
            .find();

        uint160 ownerOfTokenOne = uint160(
            uint256(
                (
                    Vm.load(
                        address(mockERC721),
                        bytes32(abi.encode(slotOfNewOwner))
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        assertEq(address(ownerOfTokenOne), alice);
    }
}
```

The last test `testAliceIsOwner` is failing and I cannot figure out why.

The error I get is:

```
[⠃] Compiling...
[⠊] Compiling 3 files with 0.8.21
[⠒] Solc 0.8.21 finished in 1.06s
Error: 
Compiler run failed:
Error (9582): Member "target" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct StdStorage storage ref.
  --> test/ETHNFTBridgeContract.t.sol:42:9:
   |
42 |         stdstore.target(address(mockERC721));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, I can see that the all the imports are correct. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this error mean that you have the wrong number of argument. I saw the documentation of foundry and you can target only one contract here you have two argument this and address(mockERC721). Tell me if this is helping you.

Comment: even after i remove `this`, I still get the same error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Add this line above `ETHNFTBridgeContract public bridgeContract;`

`using stdStorage for StdStorage;`

This would solve the issue for you.